# Java equivalent to .Net's NotSupportedException

Tags: java, .net, exception

Is there (not NotImplementedException, not supported).

Comment: +1: Simple question but something I needed to know asap.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is there anything like .NET's NotImplementedException in Java?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2329358/is-there-anything-like-nets-notimplementedexception-in-java)

Answer (score 95, accepted):

`java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException`

Or, if you use Apache Commons Lang and the operation should be supported, but has not been implemented (yet?):

`org.apache.commons.lang.NotImplementedException`

Comment: Great. Now all that remains is that this will be the #1 Google result for "notsupportedexception java"

Comment: Not implement is exactly not what I wanted btw, I want an exception that explicitly states I never intend to implement this method.

Comment: We've got Jon Skeet on our side for that one.

Comment: For me it is hit number eight now: http://www.google.co.jp/search?q=notsupportedexception+java

Comment: Just so you guys know, I just googled "java NotSupportedException" and this turns up #1

Comment: I googled "java NotSupportedException" and this turned up #2. #1 was http://stackoverflow.com/q/2329358/792238 :)

Comment: Four years after it was written, this question is still relevant. It came up #1 in my Google search, which is great, but the surprising part is that it was written by @ripper234 back when we were working together. In fact, he was probably sitting in the exact same room as I'm in right now when he wrote it. Yay for progress!

Comment: @Avish - I have a knack for asking good questions, this is how I built my StackOverflow reputation :) I'm glad this was useful for you!

Answer (score 1):

You can use either UnsupportedOperationException or NoSuchMethodException or extend the Exception class and create your own custom exception called NotImplementedException or whatever

Comment: NoSuchMethodException should really only be used in cases involving reflection, which you are using Method.invoke(...).