# Java: Disallow certain methods from extended class?

Tags: java, inheritance, overriding, overloading, extends

I've created a `Vector2D` class that extends `Point2D.Double`.

A `Vector2D` has two fields: magnitude and direction.  The extension of `Point2D.Double` allows the vector to store a starting location as well.

I like the ability to do this:

```
Vector2D myVector = new Vector2D(50, 50);  // instantiated without direction or magnitude
Point2D.Double myPoint = new Point2D.Double(myVector.getLocation());
```

However, I'd like to disallow this:

```
Point2D.Double myPoint = myVector;
```

And this:

```
Point2D.Double myPoint.setLocation(myVector);
```

Because both of these operations treat a `myVector` as if it is *just* a `Point2D.Double`.

I know that Java doesn't allow overriding or overloading of operators, so the first undesired case seems especially difficult to eliminate.  I also know that I can override `.setLocation()` with an empty method body (to prevent its use), but that's not really a great solution.

Is there a way to *disallow* `Vector2D` methods or operators that exist in `Point2D.Double`?

Comment: Prefer composition over inheritance.

Comment: Why not make a 2D Point a member of Vector, if your only reason to extend Point2D by Vector is to store a starting location?

Comment: Well, I also like methods such as `.distance()` (and the like).  I suppose I could simply write my own methods that use a private `Point2D` field for their calculations.

Comment: `Math.hypot()` is convenient for this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm failing to see the issue here. If you want Vector2D to be a subclass of Point2D.Double, then you are explicitly declaring that it *IS* a Point2D.Double. If the client wants to use it as a Point2D.Double that is allowed, and completely legitimate.

It sounds like what you are trying to accomplish is subclassing as a code reuse system, rather than as a true is-a relationship. This is generally considered an anti-pattern.

Either accept that clients can do this (even though you dislike it), or switch to a composition object instead.

Answer (score 1):

No, there is no way to disallow this.

You can, however, try a non-inheritance approach using a Vector field wrapped with your specific functionality.  One drawback is this would not allow you to accommodate the following functionality you mentioned:

```
Vector2D myVector = new Vector2D(50, 50);  // instantiated without direction or magnitude
Point2D.Double myPoint = new Point2D.Double(myVector.getLocation());
```

Not sure there is a clean way to handle this.  I wonder what your use case is that you need this sort of behavior.

Answer (score 1):

This is not possible at the *type level* due to how Java's subtype system works and the [Liskov substitution principle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liskov_substitution_principle). (There are other languages, like [Eiffel](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eiffel_(programming_language)), which *do* allow this pattern!)

> Liskov's notion of a [behavioral] subtype defines ... *if S is a subtype of T, then objects of type T in a program may be replaced with objects of type S without altering [that program]* ....

If inheritance is used *the best* that can be done is throwing a ["Not Supported Exception"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1062937/java-equivalent-to-nets-notsupportedexception) or, as pointed out, doing nothing. (Note this actually violates LSP which includes *behavioral correctness* as a requirement!)

If multiple discreet *interfaces* were used -- but they aren't here -- then it would be possible to pick'n'choose which interfaces to implement (which could be done with composition). However, with composition (or an otherwise unrelated type) one *can't use* a custom Vector2D as a [Point2D.Double](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/geom/Point2D.Double.html) and thus Java shows how easy it is to get into a bind with subtypes ;-) I lean towards *multiple* specialized interfaces these days.

If *explicit conversions* are acceptable, then `Vector2D.fromPoint2D(...)` and `Vector2D.toPoint2D(...)` is one approach that may be tolerable...

Happy coding.